# How to Send Multiple Addresses to URLRequest

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the weather.com XML service to retrieve forecast data.  I created an instance of UrlLoader and passed the entire HTTP address including credentials, location and other parameters to it.  This works very well in tandem with the XML(urlLoader.data) functionality in that I get the result for the specified location ID.  I then use E4X to trace just the nodes needed.  This is all good.

The tricky part is that I have to do this for 19 additional cities.  I've done the initial work in the Main class, Main function, private function onXmlLoaded.  I tried creating a new public function getCityName making the new URLRequest, tracing XML and adding values to my components.  However, when I attempt this, I receive:

> Error 5006: An ActionScript file cannot have more than one externally visible definition.

How can I easily setup the URLRequest to request data for all 20 cities, and parse the results thereafter?  Do I pass an array of location IDs to URLRequest, because that's the only part of the HTTP request that's different.  Do I create separate ActionScript files with their own class and functions for each of the 20 queries?

Here's the code:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public function Main()
    {
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/ASXX0274?dayf=1&link=xoap&par=1253350999&key=9a25cc224522c34a");
        var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoaded);
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
    }
    public function onXmlLoaded(event:Event): void 
    {
        XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
        var resultXML:XML = XML(urlLoader.data);
        trace(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
        trace(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
        trace(resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d").icon);

        lbllowtemp.text= String(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
        lblhitemp.text=String(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
        uicondicon.source=String(resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d").icon)+".png";

        var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
        tf.color=0xFFFFFF;
        tf.font="Arial";
        tf.size=16;
        tf.bold=true;
        lbllowtemp.setStyle("textFormat",tf);
        lblhitemp.setStyle("textFormat",tf);
        }

    public function getCanberra()
    {
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/ASXX023?dayf=1&link=xoap&par=1253350999&key=9a25cc224522c34a");
        var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoaded);
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

        XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
        var resultXML:XML = XML(urlLoader.data);
        trace(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
        trace(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
        trace(resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d").icon);

        lblCBlowtemp.text= String(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
        lblCBhitemp.text=String(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
        uiCBcondicon.source=String(resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d").icon)+".png";

        var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
        tf.color=0xFFFFFF;
        tf.font="Arial";
        tf.size=16;
        tf.bold=true;
        lblCBlowtemp.setStyle("textFormat",tf);
        lblCBhitemp.setStyle("textFormat",tf);
    }
}
```

When I debug now, I receive error 1120 access of undefined property event in my getCanberra function on the line:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop.
Obviously change links for your needs

```
var weather:Weather = new Weather( );


package {    
  public class Weather{
    public var aVars:Array = new Array();
    aVars[0] = "http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/ASXX0274?dayf=1&link=xoap&par=1253350999&key=9a25cc224522c34a"
    aVars[1] = "http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/ASXX0274?dayf=1&link=xoap&par=1253350999&key=9a25cc224522c34a"
    aVars[2] = "http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/ASXX0274?dayf=1&link=xoap&par=1253350999&key=9a25cc224522c34a"
    aVars[3] = "http://xoap.weather.com/weather/local/ASXX0274?dayf=1&link=xoap&par=1253350999&key=9a25cc224522c34a"

    public function Weather() {
      for( var i:int = 0; i<aVars.length; i++){
        var urlRequest:URLRequest=new URLRequest(aVars[i]);
        var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoaded);
        urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
      }
    }
    public function onXmlLoaded(event:Event):void {
      XML.ignoreWhitespace=true;
      var urlLoader:URLLoader=event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
      var resultXML:XML=XML(urlLoader.data);
      trace(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
      trace(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
      trace(resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d").icon);

      lbllowtemp.text=String(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
      lblhitemp.text=String(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
      uicondicon.source=String(resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d").icon)+".png";


      // note that tf has not been added to the display list so will not be visible
      var tf:TextFormat=new TextFormat  ;
      tf.color=0xFFFFFF;
      tf.font="Arial";
      tf.size=16;
      tf.bold=true;
      lbllowtemp.setStyle("textFormat",tf);
      lblhitemp.setStyle("textFormat",tf);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on looping through an array of URLs.  How should I assign resultXML to specific label controls?  For example, I'll be adding cblbllowtemp, cblblhitemp, cbuicondicon for Canberra and will do so for the other cities.  Or, is there a more optimal way of assigning the proper trace to the correct label?

Comment: The fastest way would be to pass cblbllowtemp, cblblhitemp, cbuicondicon into the constructor as parameters, however this is generally frowned upon. Another way you could use setter and getter methods to assign them. Either way would work as that will give the class a reference to those objects.

Comment: Can you give me a syntactic example of using getter/setter methods to assign them?  Also, when using your example above in the Main class which extends MovieClip, I receive error 1120 Access of undefined property aVars.  I've defined these immediately prior to my public function Weather, just as show in your snippet.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Actually, I had a better idea. We need to turn this into a generic loader class and on response get the vars. But to do this I need to know a little more info. You said you need to do this 19 times. Does this mean you have 19*3( hi,low,icon) areas to populate or are you reusing them by populating them on a selection of a city?

Comment: I have about 10 cities, each of which have hi, low and icon values.  I didn't realize I could reuse the label for different cities.  How would I go about this?  Thanks:)

Comment: Well I don't if you want to reuse it or not that is what I am asking. Will (hi,low,icon) for all 10 cities be showing at the same time? If so we need different IDs for each of the 3 items. If not you will need to make a button of some sort for each city

Comment: I think we will need icons for each city. Three to four cities are visible at one time, before the FLV pans to a new region.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this error only occurs if you have function defined outside of your class:

For example:

```
package {    
    public class YourClass {
        public function YourClass() {
            //Constructor
        }

        public function correctFunction():void {
            //No error.
        }
    }
    public function errorFunction():void {
        //will throw 5006 error.
    }
}
```